# Question on properly sizing sections to full-size regardless of the resolution of the screen?

Tags: html, css

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body{
  display:grid;
  background:#caa178;
  margin:0;
}
.navbar{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:#2c2c2c;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100vw;
  z-index:999;
  height:80px;
  border-bottom:solid;
  border-top:solid;
}
.navbar a{
  display:block;
  color:#cdcdcc;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:30px;
  float:right;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:130%;
  margin-right:20px;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}
.navbar a:hover{
  background:#3a3b3b;
  font-weight:1000;
}

.about-me{
  margin-top:100px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template:'hi hi hi hi txt txt'
                'hi hi hi hi vid vid'
                'hi hi hi hi vid vid';
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  }
.about-me1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size:330%;
  grid-area: 1/1/4/5;
  margin-top:-20px;
}
.about-me2{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-family:'MV Boli';
  grid-area: 1/5/4/7;
}
.negative{
  display:grid;
  grid-template:'vid vid'
                'vid vid';
  margin-top:-100px;
  }
.padding{
  padding:10px;
  border:0;
}

.my-work{
  display:grid;
  margin-top:100px;
  grid-template:'title title title'
                'work work work'
                'work work work';
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background:#605f5f;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
.my-work-text{
  grid-area: 1/1/2/4;
  margin-top:80px;
}
.my-work-text2{
  margin-bottom:3px;
  font-family:;
}
.work1{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  color:#cdcdcc;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
}
.work2{
  width:400px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  border-color:#caa178;
  margin: 0px 30px 15px 30px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.2s ease-out;
}
.work1:hover{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
.work2:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 5px 30px rgba(255,255,255,255);
}

.contact-me{
  display:grid;
  background:#2c2c2c;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  grid-template: 'empty empty empty empty empty'
                 'text twitter insta email number'
                 'text twitter insta email number'
                 'empty quote quote quote empty';
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#about-me">ABOUT ME</a>
    <a href="#my-work">MY WORK</a>
    <a href="#contact-me">CONTACT ME</a>
  </div>
  
  <div id="about-me"class="about-me">
    <div class="about-me1">
    <h1 style="font-family:Impact; color:#282828; text-shadow: 0 0 10px white;">Hi I'm Finn</h1>
    <p style="color:#605f5f; font-family:Lucida Handwriting">a beginner web developer...</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="about-me2">
    <h1 id="jammers-text"><center>MY FAVORITE JAMMERS BELOW<h1><br>
      <div class="negative">
    <iframe id="vid1" class="padding" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YdYwICNPDwI"></iframe>
    <iframe id="vid2" class="padding" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TgOu00Mf3kI"></iframe>
    <iframe id="vid3" class="padding" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jwCniuHdmj8"></iframe>
    <iframe id="vid4" class="padding" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kn6-c223DUU"></iframe>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
      
      
      <div id="my-work"class="my-work">
        <h1 class="my-work-text"style="font-size:500%; font-family:impact; color:#cdcdcc"><center>My Work</center></h1>
        
          <div class="work1">
            <h2 class="my-work-text2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <a href=""><img class="work2" src="https://www.iphone2lovely.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/blank-wallpaper-for-printing.png"></a>
          </div>   
        
          <div class="work1">
            <h2 class="my-work-text2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <a href=""><img class="work2" src="https://www.iphone2lovely.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/blank-wallpaper-for-printing.png"></a>
          </div>
        
          <div class="work1">
            <h2 class="my-work-text2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <a href=""><img class="work2" src="https://www.iphone2lovely.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/blank-wallpaper-for-printing.png"></a>
          </div>
        
          <div class="work1">
            <h2 class="my-work-text2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
           <a href=""><img class="work2" src="https://www.iphone2lovely.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/blank-wallpaper-for-printing.png"></a>
          </div>    
        
          <div class="work1">
            <h2 class="my-work-text2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <a href=""><img class="work2" src="https://www.iphone2lovely.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/blank-wallpaper-for-printing.png"></a>
          </div>     
        
          <div class="work1">
            <h2 class="my-work-text2">Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <a href=""><img class="work2" src="https://www.iphone2lovely.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/blank-wallpaper-for-printing.png"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="contact-me" class="contact-me">
          <h2 class="follow-text">Follow me on: </h2>
        <h3 class="twitter">Twitter</h>
        
        </div>
</html>
```

I asked this question recently and got answered by I found out that there's another problem. Using a different screen resolution on a different computer completely screws up the sections. I want each section:"about me", "contact me", and "my work" to take up the full length and width of the screen regardless of the resolution. Would I need to resize each element when the resolution size changes? Apparently 100vh and 100vw doesn't solve the problem completely. Thank you

Comment: did you try adding a meta tag with view port specified?

Comment: sorry I don't understand what's that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag